# Scroll bar is automatically added to figure element

Tags: html, css, image, markdown, figure

When I try to add an image inside a `<figure>` element, sometimes I get a vertical scroll bar next to it in my markdown editor. If I export it to HTML, it is gone, but if I export it to PDF, the scroll bar persists. This is unpleasant and ugly and I do not know how to get rid of it. This is what I use as html and CSS:

```css
figure {
    display: block;
}

figure img{
    max-width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
figcaption {
    color: #9BB4BC;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RGLj3oV.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[figure with scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nGfb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical scroll bars appears because the height of the element is not big enough, to fix this use the css attribute `height: auto;` in the figure section.

for now I interpret you want to keep the scrolling but simply disable the showing of the scrolling bar, to do this do the following.

Add `overflow: hidden;` to hide both the horizontal and vertical scrollbar.

`body { overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */ }` 
To only hide the vertical scrollbar, or only the horizontal scrollbar, use overflow-y or overflow-x:

`body { overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */ overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */ }`

source: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the end it worked best to just add: figure figcaption { overflow: hidden; }. Adding: height: auto; to figure didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the scroll bar inside the `figure` tag. Use:

```
figure::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}
```

Note this might not work in all browsers, a more compatible way would be setting `overflow: hidden` on the body or the parent tag of the figure, then set the figure tag to `overflow: scroll` in order to still be able to scroll.